# formula for desired sample size

Tags: statistics

The following is a description of the standard deviation of the sample mean.

$$\sigma(\bar X)=\sqrt {V(\bar X)}=\sqrt{\frac {N-n}{N-1}*\frac {\sigma^2}{n}}\leq D$$

Where $D$ is "a constant which must not be exceeded" (which I interpret as the desired width of the confidence interval.)

Now for my question. In order to determine $n$ (the required sample size), the formula is rearranged as:

$$n \geq \frac {N \sigma^2}{D^2*(N-1)+\sigma^2}$$

How do I move from the former version to the latter? I understand we've taken the square of the expression. I understand changing places of $n$ and $D^2$. I don't understand the missing $-n$ in the numerator though, nor the added $\sigma^2$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you square the (non-negative) quantities in the first displayed expression you get

$${(N-n)\sigma^2\over(N-1)n}\le D^2$$

Multiplying both sides by the (positive) denominator makes this

$$(N-n)\sigma^2\le D^2(N-1)n$$

Distributing the multiplication on the left hand side gives

$$N\sigma^2-n\sigma^2\le D^2(N-1)n$$

Moving the $n\sigma^2$ from left to right and factoring out the $n$ gives

$$N\sigma^2\le \left(D^2(N-1)+\sigma^2\right)n$$

Now divide both sides by the (positive) expression $\left(D^2(N-1)+\sigma^2\right)$ and you've got it.